# Arcpy code only works when run in two chunks, not as one piece

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000732, error-000539

I have a weird thing happening with my script. When I copy/paste it into the python cmd line within ArcMap, I get error messages. However, if I run the first part, then copy in the very last line by and run it by itself everything goes fine.
Here's my code:

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = r'H:\Arc'
#dem = r'C:\Users\Lucy\Documents\GISthings\DCEW_VegStatistics\miscrasters\bare1m_fl_int'
dem = r'H:\Arc\dem_coarseres'
# create and store aspect
outAspect = Aspect(dem)

'''set up vegetation rasters'''
pftVeg = r'H:\Arc\veg_4classes'
# raster of n and s aspects
veg_n = Con((outAspect < 45) | (outAspect > 315), pftVeg)
veg_s = Con((outAspect < 225) & (outAspect > 135), pftVeg)

''' buffer around weather stations '''
featureToBuffer = r'H:\Arc\DCEW_WS.shp' 
#outBuffer = r'C:\Users\Lucy\Documents\GISthings\DCEW_VegStatistics\bufferedWSveg.gdb\buff50m'
distanceField = "1000 meters"
# creates shapefile of buffers
# if you get an error here, try restarting computer to release schema lock
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(featureToBuffer, 'outBuffer', distanceField)

# Execute PolygonToRaster of buffers
valField = 'Field1'
assignmentType = "MAXIMUM_AREA"
priorityField = 'Field4'
cellSize = 0.00001  # 0.000001
arcpy.PolygonToRaster_conversion('outBuffer', valField, 'outRaster', assignmentType, priorityField, cellSize)
#outRaster = Lookup(Raster(outBuffer), 'Field1') #superfluous?

i = 4

# Process: Raster Calculator
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("Con(\"outRaster\" == i,\"veg_s\")", 'temp_s')
```

The Raster calculator line is where everything gets fuzzy. My error message is this:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 39, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   504, in      return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "", line 5, in rcexec   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 255, in
>   Con     where_clause)   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
>   result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 239, in
>   Wrapper     ["IfThen", in_conditional_raster,
>   in_true_raster_or_constant]) RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster:
>   Dataset veg_s does not exist or is not supported  Failed to execute
>   (RasterCalculator).

Does anyone know what could possibly be going on?

Edit in response to @FelixIP:

I'm using that syntax for my raster calculator because that's what model builder spit out for me. I'm still new to python, so I've been using it for training wheels. I tried your code with `expr` on one line and `Rastercalculator` on the other but I got the same error message. When I ran them by themselves everything worked perfectly. Does that make any sense? Ideally I'd like to put this within a for loop, so it would be good to not have to run it in two separate sections if possible.

Comment: Why are you using Con at the start and  acrpy.gp...("Con ..) at the end?

Comment: arcpy does not understand string in last line. Try expr=r'Con("Outraster"==%i,"veg_s")'%i      first and arcpy.gp.Rastercalculator(expr)